# How to connect to the internet via a login window?

Tags: windows, internet-connection

I am facing a problem in accessing the internet on my desktop. My ISP has provided the cable with an external modem. I plug in the one end of cable coming from modem in to the adaptor(LAN card), checked the Network Connections, and found the `LOCAL AREA CONNECTION` connected.

I checked the status of the LAN connection, and it was showing the details about how many packets the computer is sending or receiving.

I took this to mean that the internet is connected in my PC, but I am unable to view the login window into which I need to put the username and password provided by ISP. I opened Internet Explorer and navigated to `google.com` and it is not accessable.

How can I access the login window to put my login credential?
Is there any S/W that I need to install or any other hardware problem?

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a router managing your PPPOE connection (which sounds like the case), you'll need to make a new connection on your machine. Leave Local Area Connection enabled, and navigate to this window (Control Panel -> Network Connections if it's not in Start Menu):

[image]

Click **Create a new connection** then follow these steps:

- On the first screen, hit next
- On the second screen, click the **Connect to the internet** radio button and hit next
- On the third screen, click **set up my connection manually** and hit next
- I'm assuming you have a broadband connection with a username and password, so select **connect using a broadband connection that requires a username and password** then hit next
- Name your connection whatever you want and hit next
- Enter your account details and click next
- Finish

A familiar screen should pop up:

[image]

now these details should already be configured, clicking **connect** should work.

Answer (score 1):

Once you figured out how to get connected, consider placing a router between your external modem and pc. This will give you an extra layer of security by providing an external firewall and network address translation.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your Service Provider. Part of their service will be to get you connected to the internet, after all they're want your money so they need to get you online.